# Is there a way to USE Mapbox Vector Tiles with ImageMosaic?

Tags: geoserver, mapbox, vector-tiles, image-mosaic

I'm trying to use https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html
mapbox vector tiles to serve images on an Android App.

OSMDroid doesn't work properly so we are trying to use Mapbox SDK.

The problem with it is that it only support mapbox vector tiles, but to create a timeseries in GeoServer we need ImageMosaic. Using ImageMosaic we can't see the vector tiles options inside GeoWebCache settings.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Vector tiles are by definition... vector. GeoServer only supports encoding vector data with it. Image mosaic instead works only with rasters.

It's however possible to get vector data and support time, just attach a timestamp to your records and configure that attribute as the time dimension in your vector layer. Not sure how well time filtering is supported in vector tiles though, that's something you'll have to try.

Comment: Ok thanks. We were able to convert the RASTER to VECTOR GeoJson.
Is there a way now to use the GeoJSON as a data source?

Comment: There is no official way, and I would not recommend it anyways, GeoJSON is really slow as a data source. You should use ogr2ogr and turn that geojson into something more performant, like a postgis tables. Then you can publish it, and use vector tiles from there.